# Locate hidden compressed files and bigger than size

Tags: shell, sed, awk, find

I've learned that I can locate files bigger than X megabytes using:

```
$ find . -size +XM
```

But I have hidden compressed files (with any extension) (compressed by rar and zip), like:

```
i_am_hidden.ink
```

so that when I try to see the mimetype of the file (in this case, a hidden rar file):

```
$ file "i_am_hidden.ink" -b --mime-type
```

the output is:

```
application/x-rar
```

So, linux is able to determine when a hidden file is actually a compressed file.

How, on shell (terminal), list all my hidden compressed files, given a path dir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -size +XM -exec file {} --mime-type + | awk -F':' '/x-rar/{print $1}'
```

Note that I removed the `-b` flag to `file` because I want both the filename and the mime-type to output. `awk` will then parse over the input looking for `x-rar` and print just the file name which is in field #1.

If your version of `find` complains about `-exec` try replacing `+` with `\;`. It will be slower but it will work just as well.

Comment: How apply the regex to: x-rar    OR    RAR    ?

Comment: @Gabriel if you have GNU awk then just add `IGNORECASE=1` at the very end as in:  `...{print $1}' IGNORECASE=1`